# Resource Calendar

Tags: calendar

I have set up a resource Calendar which works fine,  I can add resources to the calendar to quickly see when the are available.  The problem is that I have to Add the resources each time (using the Add resources Link).   Is there not a way to show all resources by default?

Thanks

Comment: I've been looking around for a solution to this (seemingly obvious lack of functionality) and the best I've seen is some javascript to load the resources.